# ValueError: Expected 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scikit-learn, reshape

I try to make a SVC.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

df.loc[df["species"]=="setosa", "species"] = 0
df.loc[df["species"]=="versicolor", "species"] = 1
df.loc[df["species"]=="virginica", "species"] = 2

x = df.drop("species", axis="columns")
y = df.species
list = [6, 3, 5, 2]

svc = SVC()
svc.fit(x, y)
predict = svc.predict(list)
predict
```

But it show me this ValueError because my list don't have the right dimension:

`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[6. 3. 5. 2.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

I try using values.reshape(-1, 1) or only reshape(-1, 1) but it doesn´t work because it is a list.
In the Error was written that the Error is in "predict" line. help me please :)

Comment: make a minimum reproducible example, add the df as `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: Your prediction `x` variable should be similar to the training `x`. If that is the case, I assume the solution for you would just be to use numpy reshape

Comment: it doesn´t work :(

Comment: what doesn't work? aren't you able to add this? `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: I done it, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: What did you do? I'm asking you to edit your question and add your dataframe here using `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the structure of your dataframe it is hard to know for sure, but you probably just need to use `np.reshape`. See example code below:

Also don't use `list` as the name of the variable as it overrides the in-built name.

```
import numpy as np

# your code here
# ....

x_test = [6, 3, 5, 2]
n = 1 # number of rows of test data

x_test = np.array(x_test).reshape(n,x.shape[1])
predict = svc.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: now it says that something is wrong with the fit function, with this valueerror:

Comment: ValueError: Unknown label type: unknown. Maybe you are trying to fit a classifier, which expects discrete classes on a regression target with continuous values.